# Why will the destructor be called two times?

Tags: c++, class, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    Test() { cout << "Constructor is executed\n"; }
    ~Test() { cout << "Destructor is executed\n"; }
};

void fun(Test t)
{}

int main()
{
    Test t;
    fun(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Is the second destructor called by fun() function? 
I know the first one is called when t is out of scope.
Thanks for answers!!

Comment: You copy `t` (which constructs a new `Test`) when you pass `t` into `fun` by value.

Comment: But why the constructor will only be called one time while destructor will be called two times?

Comment: Constructors called twice (once each)

Comment: no I think it will call the copy constructor

Comment: It calls the constructor once when you do Test t, the copy constructor once when you call fun and then destruct each object (thus 2 destructor calls).